# How can I evaluate my (ns ...) declaration so that its requires affect the REPL?

Tags: emacs, clojure, read-eval-print-loop, cider

Given a declaration like this

```
(ns some.namespace
   (:require [foo :refer [bar]]
             [baz :refer :all]
             [quux :as moo]))

... some more definitions are here
```

How can I evaluate a file like this in the REPL, so that all of the `require`d namespaces (and possibly even when using `:import`) are immediately available in the REPL?

I'm using Emacs with Cider (nREPL based), but I guess this should apply in general?

Comment: In cider, open the file, use `C-c C-k`, then `C-c M-n` to switch to the namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you use `leiningen` to create your project and your file path relative to the project dir is `src/some/namespace.clj` then you can use `load` http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/load

`(load "some/namespace")`

then change your namespace

`(ns some.namespace)`